# Vuetify.js - How to add a lateral border in a v-card

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

How to add a colored lateral border on only one side of a v-card component.

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can target the specific Vuetify class. You can use **Chrome Dev Tools** to find out what class the v-card has and you can modify it using that class.

Example:

```
.v-content .v-card.v-sheet.theme--light {
    background-color: #ffffff !important;
    border-left: 5px solid red !important
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/bakadesu/pen/YzXWRwN)